# What is the correct Invoke-RestMethod syntax to update a VSTS WorkItem in Powershell - constructing a JSON string containing Windows paths

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

When trying to update an existing VSTS work item using Invoke-RestMethod, I keep getting the

> You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.

Here is what I'm passing

```
$Body = '[{ "op": "test", "path": "/rev", "value": 1},{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath", "value":"' + $caseIterationPath + '"},{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath", "value":"' + $caseAreaPath + '"}]'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$rootUri/_apis/wit/workitems/$($case.id)?$apiVersion" -Method PATCH -ContentType application/json-patch+json -Headers @{Authorization= $authorization} -Body $Body
```

Body expands to

```
"[{ "op": "test", "path": "/rev", "value": 1},{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath", "value":"Foo\Bar 2016.4\2016.4.02"},{ "op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath", "value":"Foo\Apps\Bar Stool\Eating"}]"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[JSON](http://json.org/) uses `\` as the *escape character***; for instance, `\t` is the escape sequence for a TAB character (Unicode codepoint `0x9`).

Therefore, **in order to use a *literal* `\` - such as in Windows paths - you must escape it as `\\`**.

**You *could* manually escape all the variable values** you use to synthesize your JSON string along the lines of **`$caseIterationPath -replace '\\', '\\'`** (sic).

However, it is **easier to construct regular PowerShell data structures first**, and then **let [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) do any required escaping** on conversion, which would also cover escaping verbatim `"` as `\"`.<sup>[1]</sup>

The simplest option is to use **[hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)** literals, `@{ ... }`; if you care about the order in which the entries are enumerated during the to-JSON conversion, use an *ordered* hashtable: `[ordered] @{ ... }`, as shown below.

In the case at hand:

```
# Sample values.
$caseIterationPath = 'c:\path\to\iteration'
$caseAreaPath = 'c:\path\to\area'

# Construct an array of hashtables to be converted to JSON later.
$Body = @(

  [ordered] @{
      op = 'test'
      path = '/rev'
      value = 1
  }

  [ordered] @{
      op = 'add'
      path = '/fields/System.IterationPath'
      value = $caseIterationPath
  }
 
  [ordered] @{
      op = 'add'
      path = '/fields/System.AreaPath'
      value = $caseAreaPath
  }

)

# Convert the array to a string containing JSON.
# ConvertTo-Json will perform any required escaping.
$jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $Body

# Invoke the REST method.
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$rootUri/_apis/wit/workitems/$($case.id)?$apiVersion" `
  -Method PATCH -ContentType application/json-patch+json `
  -Headers @{Authorization= $authorization} `
  -Body $jsonBody
```

In the code above, `$jsonBody` eventually contains the following - note how the `\` instances were properly escaped as `\\`:

```
[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
    "value": "c:\\path\\to\\iteration"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "c:\\path\\to\\area"
  }
]
```

---

<sup>[1] More generally, not constructing the JSON directly as a string also saves you from having to escape *syntactic* `"` chars. inside an overall `"..."` string, if string interpolation is needed. E.g., `@{ foo = "OS: $env:OS" } | ConvertTo-Json` is simpler than directly constructing `` "{ `"foo`" = `"OS: $env:OS`" }" ``</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to escape your back slashes in the value for AreaPath. From the example on the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-a-field), they use a double backslash.

```
    {
  "id": 299,
  "rev": 2,
  "fields": {
    "System.AreaPath": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git\\Website",
    "System.TeamProject": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "System.IterationPath": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
    "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
    "System.State": "To Do",
    "System.Reason": "New task",
    "System.CreatedDate": "2014-12-29T20:49:21.617Z",
    "System.CreatedBy": "Jamal Hartnett <fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com>",
    "System.ChangedDate": "2014-12-29T20:49:23.933Z",
    "System.ChangedBy": "Jamal Hartnett <fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com>",
    "System.Title": "JavaScript implementation for Microsoft Account",
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork": 4,
    "System.Description": "Follow the code samples from MSDN",
    "System.History": "Moving to the right area path"
  },
  "relations": [
    {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
      "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/297",
      "attributes": {
        "isLocked": false,
        "comment": "decomposition of work"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/299"
    },
    "workItemUpdates": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/299/updates"
    },
    "workItemRevisions": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/299/revisions"
    },
    "workItemHistory": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/299/history"
    },
    "html": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=d81542e4-cdfa-4333-b082-1ae2d6c3ad16&id=299"
    },
    "workItemType": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Task"
    },
    "fields": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields"
    }
  },
  "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/299"
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was a big help.